# Embedded sound player

Tags: html, audio, embed, soundcloud, wma

I'm looking for a third party embedded sound player to embed WMA files onto a page.

I'm looking for the type of player that is bold, has play and pause.

Similar to what is on offer on soundcloud.

I've had a search but they all seem to be mp3 specific, has anyone used one for wma files that you can recommend.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upload WMA files to SoundCloud.

> **What types of files can I upload?**
>
> We support AIFF, WAVE (WAV), FLAC, ALAC, OGG, MP2, MP3, AAC, AMR, and WMA files. The maximum file size is 5GB.

http://help.soundcloud.com/customer/portal/articles/1198303-what-types-of-files-can-i-upload-